# can't store image as base64 string in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend

i want to store image as string in mongodb but when i post data the string is not store and whene i modify my code it gives me 500 internal server err. i try to direct store image first but in mongodb imageurl field stay empty. so i want to convert it in base64 and store it in mongodb

## server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();
const { Buffer } = require('buffer');


const app = express();
const port = 5000;

// connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE,{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => console.log('DB Connected'));

// import the Candidate model
const Candidate = require('./candidate');

// use middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// create a route for adding a candidate
app.post('/api/addcandidate', async (req, res) => {
  const { candidate_name, party_name, imageURL } = req.body;
  try {
    if (!imageURL) {
      throw new Error('Image URL is required');
    }
    const candidate = new Candidate({
      candidate_name,
      party_name,
      imageURL: Buffer.from(imageURL.split(",")[1], "base64").toString(),
    });
    await candidate.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Candidate added successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to add candidate' });
  }
});

app.get('/api/candidates', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const candidates = await Candidate.find();
    res.status(200).json(candidates);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to get candidates' });
  }
});


// start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

## add.js

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({ candidate_name: "", party_name: "",  imageURL:"" });
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.name === "imageURL") {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setData({ ...data, [event.target.name]: reader.result });
      };
    } else {
      setData({ ...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }
  };
  

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/addcandidate";
      const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data);
      window.location = "/";
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error.response &&
        error.response.status >= 400 &&
        error.response.status <= 500
      ) {
        setError(error.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <Container>
      <Logo>
        <img src="./amazon_logo.png" alt="" />
      </Logo>

      <FormContainer >
        <h3>Add Candidate</h3>

      
          />
        </InputContainer>

        <InputContainer>
          <p>ImageURL</p>
             <FileBase64
             type="file"
             multiple={false}
             onChange={handleChange}
             value={data.imageURL}
           />
          
        </InputContainer>

        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Candidate</Button>
      </FormContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not Java...

Answer (score 0):

first, check file exist or not if exist then
use below code

```
profileimg = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');
```

you also need multer.
i used this mathod in below code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer();
// multer end

router.post("/updateprofile", verifyToken, upload.single('image'), body('name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('name Required'), body('phone').not().isEmpty().withMessage('phone Required'), async (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    try{
        var getData = await users.findOne({'_id':req.decoded.id},{_id: 1,image: 1}).exec();
        console.log(req.file);
        if(!req.file){
          profileimg= getData.image;
        }else{
          profileimg=req.file.buffer.toString('base64');
 
        }
        await users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.decoded.id,{ 'name':req.body.name ,'phone':parseInt(req.body.phone),'image':profileimg }).exec();
        return res.status(200).json({ success: 'Profile Updated' });
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(500).json({ errors: err });
    }
});
```

But I do not recommend it, as it will slow down the response and frontend will also slow down

Answer (score 0):

Try console loging to your server code to see where the error occuring. Also add a console log after `candidate.save()` to see if the candidate is successfully saved to the database. If the candidate is not being saved, you can check if there are any errors being thrown by MongoDB.

Make sure that the value is a valid URL and that it is being sent correctly in the request body.